# Java FileOutputStream String Writing

Tags: java, string, file-io, fileoutputstream

I’ve been having issues with a Java File. It's designed to write line after line in a test file as a log. Unfortunately it overwrites the same line every time I call it.

If anyone can help I would be eternally grateful as this has been driving me up the wall!

Code Below.

```
public abstract class Log {

    protected static String DefaultLogFileLocation = "c:\\LOG.txt";

    public static void ToFile(String pInputString) {
        FileOutputStream pOUTPUT;
        PrintStream pPRINT;
        try
        {
            pOUTPUT = new FileOutputStream(DefaultLogFileLocation);
            pPRINT = new PrintStream(pOUTPUT);
            pPRINT.println (pInputString + "\n");
            pPRINT.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use some Java Logging Framework? E.g. Java.util.logging, log4j, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to pass constructor parameter to specify you need to append data to file.

```
pOUTPUT = new FileOutputStream(DefaultLogFileLocation, true);
```

Also, why you don't use some Java Logging Framework? E.g. [java.util.logging](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html) or [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html)

Example of  log4j configuration to write to file:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="C:\\LOG.TXT" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %C{6} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/> 
    </layout>
  </appender> 
  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the [`FileOutputStream` constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) that has an `append` parameter.

Generally, get familiar with the Javadocs, they can answer simple questions like that much more quickly than people here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pOUTPUT = new FileOutputStream(DefaultLogFileLocation, true);`. See [FileOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)).