# Is it possible to redirect output from jnlp-started application to file?

Tags: java, jnlp

I need to save console output from application, started via `JNLP`, to some file on user machine (for example, to examine verbose jvm output, or to do quick-and-dirty logging). The application is granted all permissions.

Is that possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. If it is a jnlp-application (not applet) it Will work as a normal java application basicly

Comment: @AkselWillgert - Can you give an example? Since if I launch a normal java app, I can redirect with `java -jar <jar> 2>&1 > output.log`. How can I do it jnlp-application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095009/java-fileoutputstream-string-writing think that will work.

Comment: @AkselWillgert - I do understand that logging is good. What I am seeking, though, is the way to re-route all the output (including jvm's internal reporting data) into a file. The link you provided doesn't seem to give that - or does it?

Comment: nah only the quick and dirty logging from your app:. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472455/redirecting-a-java-web-start-app-logs-to-a-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626389/how-do-i-pipe-the-java-console-output-to-a-file fits better what you want to do

Comment: @AkselWillgert - I think that resetting System.out will do the job, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different scenarios:

1. If you have control over the Client machine executing the app, you can go with serg10's example and enable traces in the control panel.
2. If you can change the code, you may use:

   System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
3. To do logging to a file of your choise, use FileOutputStream with appender constructor:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29

Answer (score 3):

You can set debugging / logging / tracing options in the Java Control Panel.  On windows, try:

```
Control Panel - Java - Advanced - Settings - Debugging
```

and enable logging and / or tracing.  The output is written to your user home directory as per [the documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/debugger.html#jpitf).